# What is the best way to migrate bpmn files to Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, xml-parsing, drools, jbpm

Project uses Jbpm processes to handle flows.I am facing  below problems while development:

- Most of codes embedded to bpmn script tasks which there is no good IDE
  support for them, code is not readable,maintainable and etc.
- Merging bpmn files is painful if more than one developer did some
  changes for same bpmn files
- IDEs doesn't support code debugging for bpmns(Only i can see there is
  Drools setup which only applicable for bpmns on Eclipse IDE, not sure
  end-to-end debugging will be possible)

My question is what is the best way to migrate BPMN files to Java ?

Comment: Do you want to migrate entire BPMN flow logic to java  or you just want to migrate script task code to java files ?

Comment: Yes , I want to migrate entire BPMN flow logic with smarter way , looking for useful design pattern , parser or some other way to  do this migration.

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring out a useful design pattern or parser? I'm investigating how to do the same due to the same issues you mentioned.